# Error when installing Pandas library in Linux: "AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'get_include' "

Tags: python, pandas, linux

So I'm on Linux running a small Python script that I've built and it was working perfectly fine.
Some people changed some things in the Linux and I believe the Pandas library was somehow uninstalled.

When I tried to to to the command
`pip install pandas`,
it showed me this error, which I cannot solve. Can anyone help?

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f0/f99700ef327e51d291efdf4a6de29e685c4d198cbf8531541fc84d169e0e/pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-7597g6xb/pandas/setup.py", line 571, in <module>
        include.append(numpy.get_include())
    AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'get_include'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7597g6xb/pandas/
```

Comment: Adding `--verbose` flag may give more context for  the error.

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? have you done any research? I googled the error message and found this, among other things, which might be useful: [AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '\_\_version__'](/q/50311096/4518341). Some answers say to try reinstalling `numpy` or checking if you created another module named `numpy`.

Comment: Yes @wjandrea, of course, I've tried to solve it. And I did it just now. I needed to install Cython, then reinstall NumPy and then install pandas and it worked